# Does assigning module.exports to a separate object waste memory

Tags: node.js

There are two basic ways that I see Node modules being written. The first setting each function or variable you want to export to its own property on module.exports:

```
module.exports.foo = function () {
  ...
}
```

And the second is creating a new object that has the properties you want to export, and assigning module.exports to that at the end of the file:

```
var FooObject = {
  foo: function () {
    ...
  }
};
...

module.exports = FooObject;
```

A third thing that I sometimes see is setting module.exports to an object which has all the properties you want to export, but for the purposes of this discussion, that's equivalent to the first method I mentioned:

```
module.exports = {
  foo: function () {
    ...
  }
}
```

Are we wasting memory by doing it the second way (creating an object and assigning module.exports to that)? I always thought that since all assignment is a reference, a new object should be created when you do `module.exports = {...}` so these two would be equivalent. Is that not the case?

Comment: Not all assignments are references, that's only objects (including functions). Primitives like strings, numbers, booleans, etc. are always copied by value.

Comment: And it's good to note that the first option means you require the module and call it... `var foo = require('foo')();` vs the second option, which would just be `var FooObject = require('FooObject');`... because the first is declaring a function, and the second is declaring an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last two examples are equivalent. The only difference is that the second one is setting the object by name and the third is setting it by the object literal.